# Entity Framework DB First - Naming Navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first, navigation-properties, database-first

I am using Entity framework v 6.1.1 in my application.

My database has 2 tables **User, Location**.

```
User table
-----------
UserID
HomeCityId(FK -> LocationId)
CurrentCityId(FK -> LocationId)
Location table 
LocationId
LocationName
```

Using **DB First approach**, I created a Entity data model for these two tables.

The generated entity class of User table

```
public int UserId;
public int HomeCityId;
public int CurrentCityId;
public virtual Location Location { get; set; } 
public virtual Location Location1 { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to name these virtual properties as **HomeCity and CurrentCity** instead of **Location and Location1**?

Comment: chakravarthy , did you get any work around for this??

Comment: it looks like EF7 has a work around. Im' still investigating a solution for EF6

Comment: What is the EF7 workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Entity Framework Database First Approach, using MVC, Entity Framework, and ASP.NET Scaffolding, you can create a web application that provides an interface to an existing database. The automatically generate code enables users to display, edit, create, and delete data that resides in a database table. The generated code corresponds to the columns in the database table.

To add Data Annotations to the data model to specify validation requirements and display formatting-
**changes to the auto generated class by Entity Framework is not recommended**, as it is sure to get overridden whenever you update your EDMX data model, so metadata & partial class.cs files are created.

> Also, note that all the files- EDMX , PartialClasses.cs and
> Metadata.cs should reside at same location in your application
> directory.

Please refer this tutorial:
[Enhance data validation and display formatting for EF Database First with ASP.NET MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation#add-metadata-classes)